# How do I find the cosine similarity between vectors in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of tweets which contains the columns id, text, lang, created_at, location and tf-idf (Term Frequency Inverse Document Frequency) value of the text.  I need to find the result of cosine similarity on the tf-idf column. The tf-idf column contains 24 rows of which some of the rows are :

```
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.26726124191242434, 0.267261241912...
 [0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, ...
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5773502691896258, 0.0, ...
 [0.0, 0.4472135954999579, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u have a list of word vectors you can use **cosine_similarity** function from sklearn.metrics.pairwise like:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

vectors=[
        [1.0, 0.0, 3.2, 0.2, 5.6, 53,  6.8, 4.8, 5.0],
        [0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5],
        [0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [0.0, 0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 5.6, 53,],
        [1.0, 0.0, 3.2, 0.2, 5.6, 53,  6.8, 4.8, 5.0],
         ]

cosine_sim_matrix=cosine_similarity(vectors)
```

for the above example you get the value of the cosine similarity between all the vectors:

```
[[1.         0.07816742 0.         0.1013703  1.        ]
 [0.07816742 1.         0.         0.70316766 0.07816742]
 [0.         0.         1.         0.00750513 0.        ]
 [0.1013703  0.70316766 0.00750513 1.         0.1013703 ]
 [1.         0.07816742 0.         0.1013703  1.        ]]
```